# BITWISE C programming questionns

Tags: bitwise-operators

Let's take an 8-bit number (8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1).
if we want to reset(set to 0) its 5th bit alone from the right, what will be the 8-bit decimal value of AND MASK which is used to perform the above task?

Example:
8 bit number : 10110001
Expected Output : 101(0)0001

Comment: This looks more like a homework question than clarification. What do you not understand about AND that is keeping you from solving it?

Comment: are you guys keeping saying that homework again and again , but its not a homework so yeah i need help to solve that because i m weak in English and probably in Bitwise

Answer (score 0):

First we need the binary value that has this mask. That would be `11101111`, as `x AND 1 = x` and `x AND 0 = 0`.

Now we convert that value to binary.
That task should be very easy as it is just `1 +2 + 4 + 8 + 32 + 64 + 128`.

Or easier 255 - 16, as just the bit with value 16 is unset. So the decimal value is 239